# Struts2 after AJAX validation success need to redirect to another page

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am `not using struts2-jquery-plugin`. Only using `struts2-json-plugin with JQuery` latest.

*Want to `redirect/actionredirect` to another page after successful validation. If I do it like `<result type="redirect">/quiz-success.jsp</result>` OR `<result>/quiz-success.jsp</result>` is not working.*

**Question: How do you guys do it?**

```
1 - Is it possible to do redirection etc in struts.xml during AJAX request?
2 - I have to redirect/page refresh in $.ajax({ success: function (data) {} }); like below?

$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: viewData,
                    //dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    complete: postValidation,
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        Window.location = "/cms/home.action"+sessiontoken;
                    }
                });
```

**struts.xml**

```
<package name="validation" namespace="/validation" extends="json-default">
        <action name="quizAjax" class="com.myapp.action.QuizAction" method="sayHi">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
            <result name="input">/quiz-ajax.jsp</result>
            <result type="redirect">/quiz-success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `<result type="redirect">/quiz-success.jsp</result>` because you are calling the server using javascript. It's the script that gets the answer from the server, not the page so you have to handle it in your script.

Comment: @ Christian I am using __tiles__ along with __struts 2__. How can I redirect from script?

Comment: @Saipavan579 I can't help you because I don't use Tiles.

Answer (score 0):

change this line and see if this works for you:

change this

```
Window.location = "/cms/home.action"+sessiontoken;
```

to this

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href+"/cms/home.action"+sessiontoken);
```

Comment: I know Window.location work. I have 2 questions above. I wanted to know if any way to do redirection via struts.xml like <result type="redirect">/quiz-success.jsp</result>. If not than only option is what I have mentioned in question 2.